# glPolygonOffset() bugs with lines

Tags: c++, opengl, lines

I have the following code:

```
glEnable(GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_LINE);
glPolygonOffset(1,1); // or 40,40 etc... doesnt help at all
```

But the lines are still z-fighting, is this common bug or something...? My lines are 1.0f thick and i draw the lines last in the scene.

Also i have disable GL_ALPHA_TEST and GL_LINE_SMOOTH and enabled GL_BLEND and GL_COLOR_LOGIC_OP

**Edit:** i have already tried GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL, it doesnt help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_LINE` only works for polygon rendering with `glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE)`. If you're drawing primitives with `GL_LINES` it doesn't work. In this case you'll have to manually offset the vertices.

Comment: Ah, so i have to draw the lines with polygon mode then

Comment: Drawing lines as infinitely thin polygons will not work well; GL computes the normal and uses that to offset the vertices. In this case, the normal to the polygon you are drawing will be a 0 length vector.

Comment: @Tarydon This is not what I'm suggesting, `glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE)` is the built in wireframe mode of OpenGL.

Comment: @Andreas: Apologies. My comment was directed at Newbie's observation that he wanted to *draw the lines with polygon mode*.

Comment: or alternatively, offset the polygons you draw your lines over (see http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/polygonoffset.htm)

Comment: yeah im using the GL_QUADS and the wireframe mode, works perfectly, thanks.

Comment: +1 on this answer; it is explained also at question 13.040 at the page posted by Bahbar

Answer (score 4):

Try enabling GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL instead. (I presume the lines are depth-fighting with polygons you have rendered earlier?)

Comment: You may not have solved his problem, but you solved mine, 2 years later. Thanks!