# How to draw one line on top of another in OpenGL without Z-fighting

Tags: c++, opengl, gpu

I'm having the following problem. While `glPolygonOffset` works perfectly for meshes, for example when I'm trying to draw a wireframe outline on top of the object, it doesn't work for simple lines.

Here is how it works for meshes:

```
// draw object  
mTexture.enableAndBind();
gl::color( Colorf( 1, 1, 1 ) );
gl::draw( mVboMesh );
mTexture.unbind();

// overlay wireframe
gl::enableWireframe();
glLineWidth(1);
glEnable( GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_LINE );
glPolygonOffset( -1, -1 );
glColor3f( 0, 0, 1 );
gl::draw( mVboMesh );
glDisable( GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_LINE );
gl::disableWireframe();
```

[image: mesh]

For some reason it doesn't work for lines. What I'm trying to achieve is to draw a coordinate frame's arrows over a grid. I'm using the very same `GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_LINE` mode as when I was drawing lines, just like I was doing for the wireframe over the object. However in this case `glPolygonOffset( -1, -1 );` makes absolutely no difference. I've tried it with huge values like 100 and it's the same. Absolutely no effect. Here is what I'm doing:

```
// enable 3D rendering
gl::enable( GL_CULL_FACE );
gl::enableDepthRead();
gl::enableDepthWrite();

// drawing the grid
int size = 2000;
int step = 25;
gl::color( Colorf( 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f ) );
for( float i = -size; i <= size; i += step )
{
    glBegin( GL_LINES );
    glVertex3f( i, 0, -size );
    glVertex3f( i, 0, size );
    glVertex3f( -size, 0, i );
    glVertex3f( size, 0, i );
    glEnd( );
}

// drawing the arrows
glEnable( GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_LINE );
glPolygonOffset( -1, -1 );

glBegin( GL_LINES );
gl::color( Colorf( 1, 0, 0 ) );
glVertex3f( 0, 0, 0 );
glVertex3f( 100, 0, 0 );
gl::color( Colorf( 0, 1, 0 ) );
glVertex3f( 0, 0, 0 );
glVertex3f( 0, 100, 0 );
gl::color( Colorf( 0, 0, 1 ) );
glVertex3f( 0, 0, 0 );
glVertex3f( 0, 0, 100 );
glEnd( );

glDisable( GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_LINE );

// disable 3D rendering
gl::disableDepthWrite();
gl::disableDepthRead();
gl::disable( GL_CULL_FACE );
```

and an example of the Z-fighting I get:

[image: lines]

One hack I've tried and what worked perfectly is:

1. disable depth read, enable depth write
2. draw grid
3. draw arrows
4. enable depth read
5. draw other objects

However this is a very special case and while it works for a flat grid and arrows, it wouldn't work for pretty much anything else with a complex shape.

My questions are:

1. **Why does glPolygonOffset not work** for lines-on-lines while it works for lines-on-polygon?
2. **How can I fix it**, without resorting to the above hack, what only works in very specific cases?

*// I'm using Cinder as a framework, but it shouldn't matter since I'm using raw OpenGL commands*

**Update**

I've checked the answer in the first comment, and tried that method as well, however that one doesn't work either, since the result depends on the distance from the camera.

```
//// draw coordinate frame and grid
glDepthRange (0.01, 1.0);
drawGrid( 2000.0f, 25.0f );
glDepthRange (0.0, 0.99);   
gl::drawCoordinateFrame( 100.0f, 5.0f, 2.0f );

glDepthRange (0.0, 1.0);

// draw object
```

[image: mix]

Comment: possible duplicate of [glPolygonOffset() bugs with lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020451/glpolygonoffset-bugs-with-lines)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [glPolygonOffset() bugs with lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020451/glpolygonoffset-bugs-with-lines)

Answer (score 3):

I guess one hack could be to draw the line just a bit closer to the view point (let's say 0.1 closer). This should avoid z-fighting.

In order to do so, you calculate the normalized directional vector from your point to the POV position. Then you scale it with a small factor, and add it to your line point coordinates